# how to solve Kerio Control's Local Authority certificate issue with mobile applications?

Tags: networking, ssl, https, decryption, trusted-root-certificates

I'm using kerio control firewall in our company and as you know it has an option named:"Https decryption". As I want to track all of the data that users browse in the company, I have to turn it on.

I added the Local Authority certificate on all devices on the network and I have no problem tracking their browsing data.

My problem is that mobile applications like instagram, appstore and any other applications that use https for communication with their servers, does not work in our network.

When I turn https decryption OFF, these applications work perfectly, I would be happy to know the reason behind this and also a good solution for it.

Just to mention, I have imported kerio control's local authority certificate on mobile devices and turned on full trust as a root certificate option on both IOS & Android devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many mobile apps are written to only accept a specific certificate authority, or even only a specific server certificate, as a security measure known as [certificate pinning](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning#Android).

There is no workaround except for patching each app itself (e.g. removing pin-sets from the .apk manifest – there are several articles explaining how to do this, but they would need to be redone for every single app update), and after all, things like this are exactly what certificate pinning is meant to protect against.

Comment: I'm not looking for a way to track what my users are doing on their instagram. I'm actually looking for a solution to let these applications work in our network. kerio control also has an option for https decryption exceptions. but i have no idea what URL's or addresses that applications are requesting to put them in exceptions list. for example I added *.instagram.com or *.fb.com in the exceptions list but It's still not working.

Comment: Kerio must also have a request log, doesn't it? Can you confirm using a regular browser (or `openssl s_client` / `gnutls-cli`) that the exceptions you've added actually preserve the original certificates?

Comment: Yes.I just searched yahoo.com and checked the kerio log. as i told you i can see my ip address and exact searched URL that I requested from my browser. then I added yahoo.com in the https decryption exclusion list and searched again the same URL. I could no more see my requested URL in the kerio log. and that means my browser is using the original certificates to handshake with the requested servers.

Comment: Until you compare the certificates themselves, that doesn't mean anything.

Comment: do you know how should i find out which addresses or IP's those apps are rquesting for? I want to exclude those addresses so that we could open these kind of apps in our network.